# Adding subtitle while doing H.264 encoding into a Matroska container

Tags: gstreamer, embedded-linux

I have a requirement where I need to encode a v4l2src source in H.264 while using a Matroska container. If I have .mkv file with embedded subtitles it is easy to extract subtitles with

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mkv ! matroskademux ! "text/x-raw" ! filesink location=subtitles
```

From what I understand and assuming I understand correctly, during the encoding process the "subtitle_%u" pad needs to be linked to text/x-raw source using textoverlay.

```
gst-launch-1.0 textoverlay text="Video 1" valignment=top halignment=left font-desc="Sans, 60" ! mux.  imxv4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! timeoverlay ! videoconvert ! queue ! vpuenc_h264 ! capsfilter 
caps="video/x-h264" ! matroskamux name=mux !  filesink location=sub.mkv
```

I use the above pipeline but I do not get the overlay in the .mkv video. What is the correct way to encode a subtitle/text overlay while encoding a source in H.264 in a matroska container and then also later be able to extract it using the first pipeline?

- Sanchayan.

Comment: You are probably confusing two things. The first pipeline extracts a track that contains **text** data with timestamps. It's not an overlay on the image. Textoverlay and timeoverlay does the overlay on the image and doesn't add any track with text that could be extracted later. What do you want to do? First, second or both?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
  filesrc location=subtitles.srt ! subparse ! kateenc category=SUB ! mux.subtitle_0 \
  imxv4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! timeoverlay ! videoconvert ! queue ! vpuenc_h264 ! \
  capsfilter caps="video/x-h264" ! matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location=sub.mkv
```

And the subtitles.srt file may be like this:

```
1
00:00:00,500 --> 00:00:05,000
CAM 1

2
00:00:05,500 --> 00:00:10,000
That's all folks !
```